# Microsoft Office 2007 - Not enough memory to open Word

Tags: windows-xp, memory, microsoft-office-2007

Microsoft Office installation seems to have been corrupt and now when I open Word, Excel etc. I receive an error - "Not enough memory to open word". I tried reinstalling and all other options that I got googling, but in vain. Any help would be appreciated.

Computer's specs:

- 2 GB RAM
- 250 GB HDD
- Win XP
- Intel Dual Core 2.7 Ghz

Comment: It would help if you could post your memory configuration, specs, etc.

Comment: Also, you really should tell us what you've already tried. The most common fix for this seems to be renaming the normal template file (NORMAL.DOT) so that Word regenerates it from defaults when it starts. But presumably you already tried this, is that right?

Comment: 2 Gigs Ram, 250 Gigs hdd, Win XP, Intel Dual Core 2.7 Ghz

Comment: @boot13, yes I tried that and also tried reinstalling, repairing and also using the diagnostics tool. but no use

Comment: Do you actually have the memory available for it run? Seems unlikely this is actually the problem, but you don't mention that this is OK, so thought I'd ask just in case. Also, there's not much in the way of answers, but have you looked at [this](http://superuser.com/questions/52396/word-2007-out-of-memory-or-disk-space-error-on-launch) question?

Comment: Is this error in the format of a dialog box, or a very short command line 'black box' popping up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it fixed following the delete SID suggestion by BigHiller in this link http://forums.techarena.in/office-update-service/658395.htm#post4689340